# How to sort/filter merged cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, merge

I have two columns - column A, and column B. Shown below.

```
  A  |  B
 ---------
  a  |  1
  a  |  2
  b  |  3
  b  |  1
  b  |  4
  c  |  2
  c  |  3
  c  |  4
```

As you can see, column A has many redundant data, so I merged them together. Shown below. (I need to get rid of redundant data and represent them properly. That's the main task.)

```
  A  |  B
 ---------
  a  |  1
     |  2
 ---------
     |  3
  b  |  1
     |  4
 ---------
     |  2
  c  |  3
     |  4
 ---------
```

Now the problem is I cannot apply sort/filter function to both column. Error message was displayed when I want to sort the row. Filter does not work properly also, for example when I checked `a`, I should see `1` and `2` in column B, however only `1` is shown in column B.

So my question is: how can I get the sort/filter work with merged cells?

Comment: use PivotTable for your original data and than sort/filter inside PivotTable you will create...

Answer (score 3):

Fill your cells a,b,c with a color and sort on that specific color. Then for example the 1 and 2 will display when sorted on a colored cell "a"

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. I created conditional formatting to render the row color based on cell value and sorted by that color

Answer (score 0):

general solution, which works for when there are many more criteria.

Put in a helper column C

`=if(A2="",C1,A2)`

then filter based on that, it will propogate the merged data down.